# WPF : Apply Skey Transformation on Stroke

Tags: c#, wpf, transform

How can we apply Skew Transformation on Free hand drawing i.e. Stroke in WPF? 
If above is not feasible how can we slant EndCap?
I am targeting highlighter kind of slanted endpoints in strokes.

PS : We can achieve same for Shapes and other UI controls using   [SkewTransformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.skewtransform(v=vs.110).aspx)
and, 
[Stroke End Caps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokeendlinecap(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can apply transformation to almost anything (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750596(v=vs.100).aspx#transformationproperties)). What exactly is hand drawing and what is the problem?